# sqlalchemy throws an error when using foreign_key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi can someone help with this sqlalchemy code. When i invoke this code, it throws this error

> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py:425: SAWarning: Can't validate argument 'foreign_key'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named 'foreign'
> util.warn(

Code follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    email = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(String)
    lastname = Column(String)
    userid = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False) 


class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    userid = Column(Integer, foreign_key='Users.userid', nullable=False)
    internal_account_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    account_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Your `Users` class has not defined a `userid` attribute. Once you do that, then use `ForeignKey(Users.userid)` for the FK in `Account`. Also, be consistent with your naming: `Users` should be `User`.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy-paste error. I have corrected the code above

Comment: `userid` is `String` in `Users` but `Integer` in `Account`. Also, you're still using `foreign_key=` (kwarg) instead of `ForeignKey()` (object).